# How do I merge two virtual hard disks?

Tags: virtualization

I am using ubuntu on a virtual machine of disk size of 8 GBs and I was trying to compile kernel to build a module following these steps .

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-source
cd /usr/src
sudo tar xjvf linux-source-2.6.22.tar.bz2
cd linux-source-2.6.22
sudo cp /boot/config-2.6.22-14-generic .config
sudo make
sudo make modules
```

but it crashed due to lack of space so I added another virtual hard disk of 8 GBs and I don't know what to do next . I need to do the same exact steps and I am not sure if compiling should be in 
     /usr/src
but if so I want to merge the extra space from the extra hard disk into this location . Is that possible ?
**In other words , I need to connect the two hard disks .**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the new drive to ext4 with gparted or any tool you wish.

Then mount the partition at /mnt (or any location you choose)

```
sudo mount /dev/sbb1 /mnt
sudo chown your_user:your_user /mnt
```

Then put the kernel source in /mnt

```
mkdir /mnt/src
tar xjvf linux-source-2.6.22.tar.bz2 -C /mnt/src
```

Then proceed with your build.

Note: you should run make as follows, it will make the modules.

```
make -j5
```

You then use sudo to install

```
sudo make modules_install
```

FWIW there are a number of helper scripts, see

[Ubuntu Wiki compile kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)

Obviously there are a number of considerations in building a custom kernel, good luck to you.

EDIT: To merge 2 hard drives, use LVM. You will not be able to do LVM as your original install is not to LVM, so mounting the new drive is the best option.

Comment: Thank you , I will try that . but what does -j5 do ?

Comment: -j5 is a flag for make, it builds concurrently (jobs), makes the build faster. The number should be your number of CPU +1 , a higher number will not hurt. see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/make.1.html

Comment: Nice , previous compilation took ~4 hrs .

Comment: -j5 is a nice little trick =)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a second virtual drive, just expand the size of the original one.  To use the added space, you will need to boot the live cd and use gparted to expand the partition.  If you have a swap partition you may need to move it over to make room to expand the root partition.

Comment: I didn't find a way to expand the virtual disk using VBox on Win 7